# How can I make API calls via browser from Dash Plotly application

Tags: python, rest, browser, plotly-dash

I am creating a python Dash application for visualization but I want to consume API from web browser and not from dash server side code. How do I make my Dash app make browser side calls?

Comment: @furas I am a JS developer and have currently started to learn Dash Plotly. In JS we can easily fo browser API calls . In Dash cant we do browser based API calls?

Comment: As I know Dash doesn't have any special functions for this. So you can do whaterer you want - especially since  you know how to use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure that it makes much difference, but I think you would need to create a custom `Dash` component that makes the call if you need it to take place from the user's browser. You could put the API call in a callback function, but that would still be happening server side, not from the browser.